# MPAndroidChart проблема с добавлением данных

Tags: android, android-studio, диаграммы

При построении Bar Chart возникла проблема, студия ругается, не принимает данные в таком виде. Не получается добавить заголовки месяцев, а без них всё работает отлично.

```
    barChart= (BarChart) findViewById(R.id.bargraph);

    List<BarEntry> calls = new ArrayList<>();
    calls.add(new BarEntry(0, 9f));
    calls.add(new BarEntry(1, 3f));
    calls.add(new BarEntry(2, 5f));
    calls.add(new BarEntry(3, 2f));
    calls.add(new BarEntry(4, 6f));
    calls.add(new BarEntry(5, 12f));

    BarDataSet barDataSet = new BarDataSet(calls,"num");


    ArrayList<String> months = new ArrayList<>();
    months.add("Jan");
    months.add("Feb");
    months.add("Mar");
    months.add("Apr");
    months.add("May");
    months.add("June");


    BarData data;
    data = new BarData(months,barDataSet);


    data.setBarWidth(0.9f);
    barChart.setData(data);
    barChart.setFitBars(true);
    barChart.invalidate();
```

Студия говорит: 
    Error:(46, 24) error: constructor BarData in class BarData cannot be applied 
    to given types;
    required: IBarDataSet[]
    found: ArrayList,BarDataSet
    reason: varargs mismatch; ArrayList cannot be converted to 
    IBarDataSet

Comment: О чем же ругается студия нам остается только догадываться :)

Comment: @Eugene Krivenja добавил содержание ошибки

Comment: Как я понимаю, версия mpandroidchart 3.х?

Comment: Ну вроде да, я тоже так понимаю)

Comment: Указывать надо в вопросе версию, опять догадываться? :)

Answer (score 0):

Судя по официальному примеру, с версии 3 надо делать как-то так

```
ArrayList<IBarDataSet> dataSets = new ArrayList<IBarDataSet>();
dataSets.add(new BarDataSet(new BarEntry(0, 9f), "Jan");
// и дальше остальные месяца

BarData data = new BarData(dataSets);
```

Код не проверял, смотрите детали сами здесь
https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/blob/master/MPChartExample/src/com/xxmassdeveloper/mpchartexample/BarChartActivity.java